# How to use material module in angular4 project

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I am using the material component in my angular4 project. But I can't make it work and get this errors on `yarn start`:

```
chunk {inline} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 5.83 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {main} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 235 kB {vendor} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {polyfills} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 326 kB {inline} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {styles} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 161 kB {inline} [initial] [rendered]
chunk {vendor} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 3.99 MB [initial] [rendered]

ERROR in /Users/joey/dev/jump/front-end/node_modules/@angular/material/core/typings/option/optgroup.d.ts (9,22): Class 'MatOptgroup' incorrectly implements interface 'CanDisable'.
  Property 'disabled' is missing in type 'MatOptgroup'.
ERROR in /Users/joey/dev/jump/front-end/node_modules/@angular/material/core/typings/option/optgroup.d.ts (9,42): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanDisable) & typeof MatOptgroupBase' is not a constructor function type.
ERROR in /Users/joey/dev/jump/front-end/node_modules/@angular/material/progress-spinner/typings/progress-spinner.d.ts (22,22): Class 'MatProgressSpinner' incorrectly implements interface 'CanColor'.
  Property 'color' is missing in type 'MatProgressSpinner'.
ERROR in /Users/joey/dev/jump/front-end/node_modules/@angular/material/progress-spinner/typings/progress-spinner.d.ts (22,49): Type '(new (...args: any[]) => CanColor) & typeof MatProgressSpinnerBase' is not a constructor function type.
ERROR in AppModule is not an NgModule
```

In my `app.module.ts` I imported it:

```
import {MatProgressSpinnerModule} from "@angular/material/progress-spinner";

@NgModule({
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
    imports: [ MatProgressSpinnerModule ],
})
```

I have searched and someone suggests to use `typescript 2.2`. And below is my project.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "4.3.6",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.0.4",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.0.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "codelyzer": "^3.1.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ngx-mydatepicker": "^2.0.5",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/fb": "0.0.22",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "bulma": "^0.3.1",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "^5.6.0",
    "typescript": "^2.2.0"
  }
```

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1):

Roll back @angular/material back to version 4:

```
"@angular/material": "^4.0.0",
```

Version 5 is intended to work with @angular5.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But there is no `4.0.0` version. Below is the output of `yarn install` after I roll back to 4.0.0: Couldn't find any versions for "@angular/material" that matches "^4.0.0"
? Please choose a version of "@angular/material" from this list: (Use arrow keys)
❯ 5.0.4 
  5.0.3 
  5.0.2 
  5.0.1 
  5.0.0 
  5.0.0-rc.3 
  5.0.0-rc.2 
  5.0.0-rc.0 
  5.0.0-rc.1 
  5.0.0-rc0 
  2.0.0-beta.12 
  2.0.0-beta.11 
  2.0.0-beta.10 
  2.0.0-beta.9 
  2.0.0-beta.8 
  2.0.0-beta.7

Answer (score 1):

From release `5.0.0-rc0` and up, Angular Material **requires Angular 5**:

From the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-1):

> Angular Material now requires Angular 5, which itself requires TypeScript 2.4+ and RxJS 5.5.2+

Anyways, here's a [guide](https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/) on how to upgrade to Angular 5.